# confusing and oddly specific dns issue

Tags: pi-2, ethernet, dns

I primarily use the raspberry pi in two locations, at my school and at home, where i connect to the internet using LAN. The school's network seems to enforce the use of a specific dns server, which i was able to identify and use without issue after editing Resolv.conf. while i am at home, however, this dns server does not work, so i use 8.8.8.8 instead. the name resolution seems to work, but when i try to ping a website, instead of the website's actual IP address, it will respond with an IPV6 address with a host name that is completely different than the one i pinged. the hostnames and IP addresses seem to depend on the address i try to ping and are all different. trying to go to a website regardless results in a host resolution error. this issue is only present on the raspberry pi and only present at home. using 8.8.8.8 on my desktop, which is connected to the same router, works with no issues, and this has never been a problem with any other systems.

what is going on, and why is this only happening to the raspberry pi?

Comment: Do you use Raspbian? If so then don't edit `/etc/resolv.conf`. It is managed by `resolvconf` and will be overwritten. Is there a DHCP server running on your home network? Please edit the question and add an example with that confusing ping command. And please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: In addition to the stuff @Ingo wants get the output from the following commands: ```ifconfig -a;```
```ip route;```
```ping -c3 $(ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}');```
```ping -c3 8.8.8.8;```
```cat /etc/resolv.conf;```
```ping -c3 google.com;```